# AVAudioSession setup with AVCaptureSession `automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession` set to false

Tags: avfoundation, avcapturesession, avaudiosession

I'm having issues with using `AVCaptureSession` and `AVAudioSession` working together.
From what I read there are multiple issues which Apple hasn't provided with a good documentation especially with understanding how these two framework interact.

So on my app I'm recording Audio & Video (in the foreground) and Audio (in the background).

For the foreground recording I'm using:

- Two `AVCaptureSession` each with a media type on for video and one for audio
- Each has `AVCaptureDeviceInput` & `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` (the one for audio has `AVCaptureAudioDataOutput`)
- `AVAssetWriter` and two `AVAssetWriterInput` to create the media file

For the background recording I'm using:

- `AVAudioRecorder`

From what I understood, in order to fully support Bluetooth devices it is recommended to set the `automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession` to `false`, and from this properties docs it says: *If you set this property’s value to false, your app is responsible for selecting appropriate audio session settings. Recording may fail if the audio session’s settings are incompatible with the capture session.*

Now my issue is that the recording will fail about 90% of the times with  *`NSOSStatusErrorDomain -12780`*

But if I remove the audio input of the `AVCaptureSession` it works 100% of the times.

My `AVAudioSession` setup is like so:

```
        do {
            let audioOptions = AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions.mixWithOthers.rawValue |
                AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions.allowBluetooth.rawValue |
                AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions.defaultToSpeaker.rawValue
            try audioSession.setCategory(
                .playAndRecord,
                mode: .videoChat,
                options: AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions(rawValue: audioOptions)
            )
        } catch {
            print("Failed to set audio session category.")
        }
```

So my question is:
What is the proper setup settings for `AVAudioSession`? because it seems that it all revolves around the audio recording.

Thanks!

Comment: did you happen to resolve? im running into the same issue where my captureSession started to not work once i had to set automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession = false

Comment: @Chris Yeah I've solved it, but not by using this combination above.

Comment: I ended up using AudioUnits to get the audio data then converting the buffers into CMSampleBuffers and caching them with the VideoBuffers using AVAssetWriter